# XAML CommandBinding does not exist within local namespace?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add custom commands to my project in C#. To do this I've added a new class to my project:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DataBindingHuiswerk
{
    public static class CustomCommands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Add = new RoutedUICommand(
            "Add",
            "Add",
            typeof(CustomCommands),
            new InputGestureCollection()
            {
                new KeyGesture(Key.F1, ModifierKeys.Control)
            }
        );

        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Change = new RoutedUICommand(
            "Change",
            "Change",
            typeof(CustomCommands),
            new InputGestureCollection()
            {
                new KeyGesture(Key.F2, ModifierKeys.Control)
            }
        );

        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Delete = new RoutedUICommand(
            "Delete",
            "Delete",
            typeof(CustomCommands),
            new InputGestureCollection()
            {
                new KeyGesture(Key.F3, ModifierKeys.Control)
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Next I'm trying to bind these in my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="DataBindingHuiswerk.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBindingHuiswerk"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommands.Add" Executed="AddCommand_Executed" CanExecute="AddCommand_CanExecute" />
```

However, this returns me:

> The name "CustomCommands" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:DataBindingHuiswerk"

Now I'm probably wrong here, but to me `CustomCommands` clearly exists within the `DataBindingHuiswerk` namespace? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does "returns me" mean it won't build?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No it means my project says "Invalid Markup" and when hovering the mouse on the error underlined part: `Command="local:CustomCommands.Add"` it returns that message.

Comment: Ahh. Will it build?

Comment: This does not make sense. This is not a situation where you have to use custom bindings. If you are doing code behind, just stick to that and use `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` events instead.

Comment: @EdPlunkett No it doesn't build. The same error is returned when trying to build

Comment: So it *does* mean it won't build. I'm not a dentist, you know.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Haha I know. Sorry I should've tested if it would build or not first. My mistake

Comment: However unusual, I used to have this error coupled with other bugs in code. It will show multiple errors, but this one will be the first so I'll think its my only error and keep trying to fix it. Make sure there are no other warnings at all, as a start.

Comment: @KosalaW I'm not asking whether it makes sense to use custom bindings here or not. It doesn't influence the question at all. I'm simply learning how to use custom commands. It's not something that will be used in a product for anyone.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I figured it out. Answered my own question, but I think I'm going to delete the question because it's a simple typographical error.

Comment: The fact that the error message was so bizarrely misleading suggests that the question is worth keeping.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Hmm ye you have a point there. I'll leave it :)

Comment: @EdPlunkett As long as you are not planning to use it in production, it should be ok. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @KosalaW Ok, I won't.

Comment: @EdPlunkett The whole world is doomed if you do do mate, so leave it to rest of us xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues in your code.

Xaml should be like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommands.Add" Executed="AddCommand_Executed" CanExecute="CommandBinding_OnCanExecute" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Command="local:CustomCommands.Add">Add</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind should be like this.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("sdfgsdgdsgdf");
    }

    private void CommandBinding_OnCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ye I knew these parts. The problem was indeed the `<Window.CommandBindings>` missing from the xaml as I pointed out in my own answer. I will mark yours as answered so the question doesn't remain unanswered. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I simply forgot to wrap `<CommandBinding />` inside `<Window.CommandBindings />`. The solution to the problem was:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:CustomCommands.Add" Executed="AddCommand_Executed" CanExecute="AddCommand_CanExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Normally I would've deleted the question because it's a simple typographical error, but (as Ed Plunkett correctly pointed out in the comments) the error message is very misleading as to what's really going on. Therefor I'll leave it intact.